# Adding list of items in Richtextblock in uwp to print the list of items?

Tags: c#, uwp, richtextblock, richtextblockoverflow

I am creating the **UWP** application. I want to add the printing feature to my project. So that i am using **RichTextBlock** to send the page to preview. All Preview is working fine. But i have huge error when the list of items get in run time i.e(From data base). overflow is not working properly when the items get from the run time. But it works properly with predefined set of paragraphs. please help me to solve the problem.

```
<RichTextBlock x:Name="takeprint"  Grid.Row="1" Width="770"  OverflowContentTarget="{Binding ElementName=ContinuationPageLinkedContainer}"  Margin="0 10 0 0" >
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <RichTextBlock>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <InlineUIContainer>
                            <Grid x:Name="top"  Margin="0 30 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"   Background="Black">
                                <RelativePanel Height="40" Width="auto" Background="#32b38c">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="sno" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" Text="Sno" Width="40" Margin="5,10,10,10"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="name" RelativePanel.RightOf="sno" Text="Name" Width="90" Margin="0,10,0,10"  Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="schoolname" RelativePanel.RightOf="name" Text="School Name" Width="90" Margin="5,10,0,10"   Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="appdate" RelativePanel.RightOf="schoolname" Text="App Date" Width="70" Margin="5,10,0,10"  Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="returndate" RelativePanel.RightOf="appdate" Text="Return Date"  Width="70" Margin="5,10,0,10" Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}"  />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="checkno" RelativePanel.RightOf="returndate" Text="CheckNo"  Width="80" Margin="5,10,0,10"  Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}" VerticalAlignment="Center"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="fees" RelativePanel.RightOf="checkno" Text="Fees" Width="70" Margin="0,10,0,10"   Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="CabCost" RelativePanel.RightOf="fees" Text="CabCost" Width="70" Margin="0,10,0,10"   Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="ticamt" RelativePanel.RightOf="CabCost"  Text="Tic amt"  Width="55" Margin="0,10,0,10"  Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="totalcost" RelativePanel.RightOf="ticamt" Text="Total Cost" Width="100" Margin="0,10,0,10"   Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </RelativePanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </InlineUIContainer>
                    </Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph></Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <InlineUIContainer>
                            <ItemsControl x:Name="Reportview">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <RelativePanel Margin="0 20 0 0">
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="sno" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Sno}"   VerticalAlignment="Center"  Width="40" Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}" />
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="name" RelativePanel.RightOf="sno" Text="{Binding Name}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"  Width="90" Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}" />
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="schoolname" RelativePanel.RightOf="name" Text="{Binding SchoolName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"  Width="90" Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}" />
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="appdate" RelativePanel.RightOf="schoolname" Text="{Binding AppDate1}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="90" Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="returndate" RelativePanel.RightOf="appdate" Text="{Binding ReturnDate1}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="90" Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="checkno" RelativePanel.RightOf="returndate" Text="{Binding CheckNo}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="60" TextWrapping="Wrap"    Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="fees" RelativePanel.RightOf="checkno" Text="{Binding Fees}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="70" TextWrapping="Wrap"    Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="Cabcost" RelativePanel.RightOf="fees" Text="{Binding CabCost}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="70" TextWrapping="Wrap"    Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="ticketamount"  RelativePanel.RightOf="Cabcost" Text="{Binding TicketAmount}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="60" TextWrapping="Wrap"   Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="totalcost" RelativePanel.RightOf="ticketamount" Text="{Binding TotalCost}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Style="{StaticResource ptextblock}"/>
                                        </RelativePanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </InlineUIContainer>
                    </Paragraph>
                </RichTextBlock>
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBlock>
    <RichTextBlockOverflow x:Name="FirstLinkedContainer"  OverflowContentTarget="{Binding ElementName=ContinuationPageLinkedContainer}" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <RichTextBlockOverflow x:Name="ContinuationPageLinkedContainer" Grid.Row="3"/>
```

overflow is not happened even the list have more number of rows it shows only the height of the grid.rows height. But overflow works properly when the predefined set of paragraphs. without any changes inside the code.

```
   <RichTextBlock x:Name="takeprint"  Grid.Row="1" Width="770"  OverflowContentTarget="{Binding ElementName=ContinuationPageLinkedContainer}"  Margin="0 10 0 0" >
     <Paragraph>Sed convallis ornare velit et interdum. Donec sapien neque, aliquet consequat convallis at, interdum et enim. Donec iaculis, lectus vel pulvinar cursus, lectus diam interdum ante, a rhoncus tortor quam porta metus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam pulvinar fringilla vestibulum. Pellentesque pharetra nunc in turpis tempus sed faucibus ligula sagittis. Praesent hendrerit est vitae lorem mattis in porttitor urna vestibulum. Phasellus adipiscing aliquam libero ac adipiscing. In a erat sit amet erat sollicitudin bibendum id vitae dui. Vestibulum non consequat nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris elit nisi, blandit et porttitor quis, malesuada nec mi.</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph></Paragraph>
        <Paragraph >Aliquam erat volutpat. In non urna ut libero ultricies fringilla. Proin tellus neque, aliquam lacinia consequat at, vulputate et arcu. Maecenas odio nunc, lobortis sit amet pulvinar sit amet, accumsan et leo. Suspendisse erat lectus, commodo ac auctor eget, rutrum in mi. Suspendisse potenti. Proin ac elit non lacus rutrum mollis. Vivamus venenatis, tellus vel placerat lacinia, arcu ligula dignissim orci, consectetur consectetur eros massa vel nulla. Quisque malesuada iaculis ornare. Nullam tincidunt accumsan egestas. Mauris sit amet scelerisque arcu. Proin euismod sodales magna faucibus commodo. Nam in fringilla orci. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph></Paragraph>
        <Paragraph >Sed eget nunc quis tellus interdum aliquet. Suspendisse rhoncus malesuada nisi a imperdiet. Suspendisse ullamcorper mi sed purus tristique interdum. Mauris lobortis, ante ultrices varius consequat, eros ante hendrerit enim, vulputate convallis dui ligula eget velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec eget lectus fermentum nisi consequat dictum. Sed volutpat justo non purus semper vel pretium enim molestie. Nam consectetur, lectus quis feugiat malesuada, neque nunc faucibus velit, nec vehicula risus est id sapien. Vestibulum ut metus massa, ut placerat lacus. Fusce condimentum vehicula tortor, nec vestibulum ligula iaculis ut. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus tincidunt scelerisque erat, ut fermentum urna pretium eu. Donec ut nibh orci. Curabitur sodales metus dictum mauris varius vitae mollis tellus pulvinar. Quisque facilisis ligula sed risus laoreet non lacinia odio luctus. Nam lobortis rhoncus felis vitae ultrices.</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph></Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>Aliquam erat volutpat. In non urna ut libero ultricies fringilla. Proin tellus neque, aliquam lacinia consequat at, vulputate et arcu. Maecenas odio nunc, lobortis sit amet pulvinar sit amet, accumsan et leo. Suspendisse erat lectus, commodo ac auctor eget, rutrum in mi. Suspendisse potenti. Proin ac elit non lacus rutrum mollis. Vivamus venenatis, tellus vel placerat lacinia, arcu ligula dignissim orci, consectetur consectetur eros massa vel nulla. Quisque malesuada iaculis ornare. Nullam tincidunt accumsan egestas. Mauris sit amet scelerisque arcu. Proin euismod sodales magna faucibus commodo. Nam in fringilla orci. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph></Paragraph>
        <Paragraph >Sed eget nunc quis tellus interdum aliquet. Suspendisse rhoncus malesuada nisi a imperdiet. Suspendisse ullamcorper mi sed purus tristique interdum. Mauris lobortis, ante ultrices varius consequat, eros ante hendrerit enim, vulputate convallis dui ligula eget velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec eget lectus fermentum nisi consequat dictum. Sed volutpat justo non purus semper vel pretium enim molestie. Nam consectetur, lectus quis feugiat malesuada, neque nunc faucibus velit, nec vehicula risus est id sapien. Vestibulum ut metus massa, ut placerat lacus. Fusce condimentum vehicula tortor, nec vestibulum ligula iaculis ut. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus tincidunt scelerisque erat, ut fermentum urna pretium eu. Donec ut nibh orci. Curabitur sodales metus dictum mauris varius vitae mollis tellus pulvinar. Quisque facilisis ligula sed  risus laoreet non lacinia odio luctus. Nam lobortis rhoncus felis vitae ultrices.</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>Sed convallis ornare velit et interdum. Donec sapien neque, aliquet consequat convallis at, interdum et enim. Donec iaculis, lectus vel pulvinar cursus, lectus diam interdum ante, a rhoncus tortor quam porta metus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam pulvinar fringilla vestibulum. Pellentesque pharetra nunc in turpis tempus sed faucibus ligula sagittis. Praesent hendrerit est vitae lorem mattis in porttitor urna vestibulum. Phasellus adipiscing aliquam libero ac adipiscing. In a erat sit amet erat sollicitudin bibendum id vitae dui. Vestibulum non consequat nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris elit nisi, blandit et porttitor quis, malesuada nec mi.</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph></Paragraph>
        <Paragraph >Aliquam erat volutpat. In non urna ut libero ultricies fringilla. Proin tellus neque, aliquam lacinia consequat at, vulputate et arcu. Maecenas odio nunc, lobortis sit amet pulvinar sit amet, accumsan et leo. Suspendisse erat lectus, commodo ac auctor eget, rutrum in mi. Suspendisse potenti. Proin ac elit non lacus rutrum mollis. Vivamus venenatis, tellus vel placerat lacinia, arcu ligula dignissim orci, consectetur consectetur eros massa vel nulla. Quisque malesuada iaculis ornare. Nullam tincidunt accumsan egestas. Mauris sit amet scelerisque arcu. Proin euismod sodales magna faucibus commodo. Nam in fringilla orci. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph></Paragraph>
        <Paragraph >Sed eget nunc quis tellus interdum aliquet. Suspendisse rhoncus malesuada nisi a imperdiet. Suspendisse ullamcorper mi sed purus tristique interdum. Mauris lobortis, ante ultrices varius consequat, eros ante hendrerit enim, vulputate convallis dui ligula eget velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec eget lectus fermentum nisi consequat dictum. Sed volutpat justo non purus semper vel pretium enim molestie. Nam consectetur, lectus quis feugiat malesuada, neque nunc faucibus velit, nec vehicula risus est id sapien. Vestibulum ut metus massa, ut placerat lacus. Fusce condimentum vehicula tortor, nec vestibulum ligula iaculis ut. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus tincidunt scelerisque erat, ut fermentum urna pretium eu. Donec ut nibh orci. Curabitur sodales metus dictum mauris varius vitae mollis tellus pulvinar. Quisque facilisis ligula sed risus laoreet non lacinia odio luctus. Nam lobortis rhoncus felis vitae ultrices.</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph></Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>Aliquam erat volutpat. In non urna ut libero ultricies fringilla. Proin tellus neque, aliquam lacinia consequat at, vulputate et arcu. Maecenas odio nunc, lobortis sit amet pulvinar sit amet, accumsan et leo. Suspendisse erat lectus, commodo ac auctor eget, rutrum in mi. Suspendisse potenti. Proin ac elit non lacus rutrum mollis. Vivamus venenatis, tellus vel placerat lacinia, arcu ligula dignissim orci, consectetur consectetur eros massa vel nulla. Quisque malesuada iaculis ornare. Nullam tincidunt accumsan egestas. Mauris sit amet scelerisque arcu. Proin euismod sodales magna faucibus commodo. Nam in fringilla orci. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph></Paragraph>
        <Paragraph >Sed eget nunc quis tellus interdum aliquet. Suspendisse rhoncus malesuada nisi a imperdiet. Suspendisse ullamcorper mi sed purus tristique interdum. Mauris lobortis, ante ultrices varius consequat, eros ante hendrerit enim, vulputate convallis dui ligula eget velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec eget lectus fermentum nisi consequat dictum. Sed volutpat justo non purus semper vel pretium enim molestie. Nam consectetur, lectus quis feugiat malesuada, neque nunc faucibus velit, nec vehicula risus est id sapien. Vestibulum ut metus massa, ut placerat lacus. Fusce condimentum vehicula tortor, nec vestibulum ligula iaculis ut. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus tincidunt scelerisque erat, ut fermentum urna pretium eu. Donec ut nibh orci. Curabitur sodales metus dictum mauris varius vitae mollis tellus pulvinar. Quisque facilisis ligula sed  risus laoreet non lacinia odio luctus. Nam lobortis rhoncus felis vitae ultrices.</Paragraph>
    </RichTextBlock>
    <RichTextBlockOverflow x:Name="FirstLinkedContainer"  OverflowContentTarget="{Binding ElementName=ContinuationPageLinkedContainer}" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <RichTextBlockOverflow x:Name="ContinuationPageLinkedContainer" Grid.Row="3"/>
```

This code works properly then what is the problem in above code.

Comment: `InlineUIContainer` is not supported in this scenario. Texts can be put into overflow automatically, but `InlineUIContainer` can't. If you want to show contents in other overflows, you need to put them is other `Paragraph`.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT actually i did that only in the above code everything inside the paragraph. how can i use the text inside of paragraph